# When will $G=\{s \in S_n \mid s^3=id \}$ be a normal subgroup of $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\{s \in S_n \mid s^3=id \}$

1. For which $n \in \mathbb N$ does $G \subseteq A_n$?
2. For which $n \in \mathbb N$ is $G$ a subgroup? For which is it a normal subgroup?

So to me it seems that for (1) it's for every $n$, since $s^3=id$ means $s$ must be even, since we get $s \cdot s \cdot s=id$, and $\mathrm{id}$ is an even permutation. The only way that would happen is if $s$ were even.

For (2), it seems like it is a subgroup for $n=1, 2, 3$. Normal subgroup for $n=1$ and $n=2$. Isn't $\{id\}$ the only normal subgroup of $S_n$ except $A_n$? and since $G \subseteq A_n$ for every $n$, we get $G$ is a normal subgroup only for $n=1,2$ (since then $G=\{\mathrm{id}\}$)?

How can I get the general solution for this? Would appriciate hints!

Thanks!

Comment: Your first two are correct. But note that it will be a normal subgroup whenever it is a subgroup (this is true for the given subset of any group). It is not until $n\geq5$ that $A_n$ is the only non-trivial proper normal subgroup of $S_n$.

Comment: Why is claim "it will be a normal subgroup whenever it is a subgroup" correct?

Comment: Because if $x^3 = id$ then $(gxg^{-1})^3 = gx^3g^{-1} = gg^{-1} = id$ so the subgroup also contains $gxg^{-1}$ for any $g$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* When $n>3$, can you find two three cycles $\sigma$ and $\tau$ such that $\sigma\tau$ does not have order $3$?